# Turkish citizen, US green card holder, but living in UK - Germany transit visa?

Tags: visas, germany, transit

If my husband is a Turkish citizen, USA green card holder and lives in the UK, will he need a Germany transit visa to pass through Frankfurt on our way to Turkey?

Comment: Is he departing from the UK, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 3):

As long as he's not going on a Domestic flight he won't need a transit visa according [Schengen Visa requirements from Germany](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/__Transit__Visa.html):

> Nationals from the above list are entitled to transit through the international transit zones without an airport transit visa:
>
> 1. If they hold a valid visa for the United States of America
> 2. If they return from the USA after having used the visa (however,
>       the return has to occur within latest four days after expiration
>       of the validity of the visa)
> 3. If they hold one of the following residence permits:
>
>    - Form I-551 permanent resident card (valid for 2 to 10 years),
>    - Form I-551 Alien registration receipt card (valid for 2 to 10 years),
>    - Form I-551 Alien registration receipt card (no expiry date),
>    - Form I-327 Re-entry document (valid for two years — issued to
>        holders of a I-551),
>    - Resident alien card (valid for 2 or 10 years or no expiry date.
>        This document guarantees the holder’s return only if his stay
>        outside the USA has not exceeded one year),
>    - Permit to re-enter (valid for two years. This document guarantees
>        the holder’s return only if his stay outside the USA has not
>        exceeded two years),
>    - Valid temporary residence stamp in a valid passport (valid for one
>        year from the date of issue).